# what does the snippet mean?

Tags: ruby

I am working with Ruby scripting language. I have a snippet here. Just want to know what is happening inside that with in the loop. Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

presidents = ["Ford", "Carter", "Reagan", "Bush1", "Clinton", "Bush2"]

for ss in 0...presidents.length
  print ss, ": ", presidents[presidents.length - ss - 1], "\n";
end
```

I know that it is to print the array in reverse order, but my intention is to know what is happening in

```
"presidents[presidents.length - ss - 1]"
```

Please help me understanding this. I am really confused with this.

Comment: It's a good idea to link to the website that had the code snippet in question, so that people answering the question can see it in context. Was it http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/basictutorial.htm ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that, whoever wrote this code, he was still learning Ruby :-p. That's more idiomatic and, I hope, self-explanatory:

```
presidents.reverse_each.with_index do |name, index|
  puts "#{index}: #{name}"
end
```

About `presidents[presidents.length - ss - 1]`: `ss` starts at 0, so `length-0-1 = length-1` -> last element of `presidents`. On the last iteration of the loop you have `length - (length-1) -1 = 0`, so the first element of `presidents` is shown. A simple reverse, nothing fancy.

Comment: `.reverse_each.with_index` avoids the extra array.

Comment: @steenslag: a bit more tricky for a novicer to understand, but yes, conceptually it's the right way if you are going to loop over values.

Comment: One website that had this code snippet also had many other ways of approaching the problem. http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/basictutorial.htm

Comment: @Andrew: it makes sense, loops can be a good example of progressive improvement (from naive C-style till more idiomatic functional Ruby).